# Android: Requesting permission from an activity and launching a service does not grant the permission to the service?

Tags: android, android-activity, permissions, android-service, android-permissions

I have an app which has an option checkbox in preferences which triggers a background service when its ticked. The service requires permission to record audio from user, so I requested permission from the preferences activity itself when the user checks the box, and started the service once the permission is granted. This is my code:

```
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {

        Log.e("voice trigger button clicked 1") ;
        CheckBoxPreference cpb=(CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("keyVoiceTrigger");
        cpb.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            Context context=getActivity();


            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                Log.e("voice trigger button clicked 1") ;
                int permissionCheck1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
                //int permissionCheck2 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                if ((permissionCheck1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) ){
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 1);
                    return false;
                }

                context.startService(new Intent(getActivity(), com.speechrecognition.android.speak.service.VoiceService.class));
                return true;
            }
        });

        Preference pref = findPreference(key);
        if (pref instanceof ListPreference) {
            ListPreference lp = (ListPreference) pref;
            if (mKeyMaxResults.equals(key)) {
                updateSummaryInt(lp, R.plurals.summaryMaxResults, lp.getEntry().toString());
            } else {
                pref.setSummary(lp.getEntry());
            }
        }
    }
```

Now when I run the app it asks for permission to record audio, the service is started, but when I check for permission inside the service:

```
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"yolololo",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG,"service started");

    // Check if user has given permission to record audio
    int permissionCheck1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
    if (permissionCheck1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        runRecognizerSetup();
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

The method runRecognizerSetup() doesnt start. Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`requestPermissions` is not a synchronous operation: it displays a dialog to the user where they must approve the permission. It is only in [onRequestPermissionsResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[])) that you learn if the user approved or denied the permission.

You should move your call to `startService` to the `onRequestPermissionsResult()` method and only launch it when the request was approved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to request the permission from the service instead. But from what I can remember that's a little tricky.

You probably need to

> Check permission in service
>
> ```
> If it's denied: Display notification through activity and request permission
> ```

I'll see if I can dig up how I solved it.

Comment: You cannot request permissions from services.